# Is this RAM compatible with my laptop?

Tags: memory, thinkpad, lenovo-laptop

I'm embarrassingly uneducated when it comes to RAM, I should be better, but I usually just punch my make and model into Crucial's site and trust it. Crucial's 8GB kit is rather pricey for me at the moment. I want to upgrade the RAM in my **ThinkPad T510** with the **Kingston KTA-MB1066K2/8G**, which is apparently meant for Macs (not that Apple uses proprietary RAM, but that's how it's advertised). I found a particularly good deal on this particular RAM, so that's why I'm going for this.

Answer (score 1):

The ThinkPad T510 memory specifications are the following

> - PC3-8500 or PC3-10600 Non-Parity (NP) Double Data Rate Three (DDR3)
>     Technology (*)
> - 1GB, 2GB or 4GB memory
> - Supports up to 8GB (for T510) or 16GB (for W510) maximum memory

[Detailed specifications - ThinkPad T510, T510i, W510](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/pd003320)

Kingston KTA-MB1066K2 is DDR3-1066 (i.e. PC3-8500) memory which has a 133.33 MHz memory clock

- PC3-8500 runs at 133.33 MHz and is considered to be DDR3-1066 memory
- PC3-10600 runs at  166.67 MHz and is considerd to be DDR3-1333 memory

[Kingston Technology 8GB Kit (2x4 GB Modules) 1066MHz DDR3 SODIMM Notebook Memory for Select Apple iMac's and Macbooks KTA-MB1066K2/8G](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001PS9UKW)

This means Kingston KTA-MB1066K2 is **fully supported by your hardware**.